# CRON Check for all iterations

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, cron

[image]I have a scheduler with the CRON expression as

```
0 30 13 5-5 9-10  ?  2018-2018
```

From the above my thinking is it will run from sep 5th to oct 5th of 2018. But it's breaking in month end. Is there a way to check for all iterations of CRON in apex?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not in Apex, but tools like [this site](https://cronexpressiondescriptor.azurewebsites.net/) can help you figure it out. Note that what you're trying to do is impossible; your expression, as read, will only work at 1:30 PM on the 5th of September and October, 2018 (two times total). Each element of the CRON expression must independently match, so you can't specify a start/end date that way with a simple CRON expression. In this case, it'd be better to use the scheduling user interface, which allows you to specify proper start/end dates. As a CRON expression, you'd need *two* jobs, the first describing runs from the 5th of September to the end of the month, then a second for October from the first through the 5th:

```
0 30 13 5-31 * ? 2018
0 30 13 1-5 * ? 2018
```